# How can insert all data from an dataframe into a dictionary

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, for-loop

I'm trying to insert all values that have a specific number on the category into a dictionary:

My data frame is like this:

```
    Data        Código de barras    Categoria       Marca    
2   2022-12-31  590688144812        55              AW0152 
3   2022-12-31  No                  34              CÂMARA  
4   2022-12-31  No                  34              CÂMARA FULL
```

And when my dictionary has data like this:

```
Data                             2022-12-31 00:00:00
Código de barras                                  No
Categoria                                         34
Marca                                     CÂMARA FULL
```

I tried this:

```py
for i,j in tabela_insere.iterrows():
    if j["Categoria"] == 34:
        print(j)
        dados = [j.to_dict()]
```

The problem is that when I try inserting data in the dictionary, it only inserts the last row, like in the dictionary above, instead of adding the two rows with the categoria 34, only inserting the last row.
I think the problem is in the dictionary because e created inside the `for` loop, but I don't know how to do it in another way.

Comment: why didn't your code work.   it should have convert the row into a dictionary and stored the dictionary in a new column using loc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best you can do is convert the dataframe into a *json tree* and then walk the tree using recursion.

```py
import pandas as pd
import io
#from pandas.compat import StringIO
from io import StringIO

data="""Data    Codigo  de barras    Categoria  Marca    
2022-12-31  590688144812    55  AW0152
2022-12-31  No  34  CÂMARA  
2022-12-31  No  34  CÂMARA FULL"""
   
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep='\t')
output = df.to_json(orient='records')
#output
```